# Access com.sun.* classes from openjdk11

Tags: java

I have a Spring Boot application and I want to use the class `com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean`, and the method `getThreadAllocatedBytes` to collect information about allocated bytes in my application. I dockerized it and used OpenJDK 11 in the dockerfile, because Oracle JDK cannot be dockerized. I'm using docker image `jboss/base-jdk:11` and deploy the application in a Wildfly 16.

Unfortunately OpenJDK does not support the `com.sun.*` packages. Is there any way I can work around this problem and use `com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes` in an OpenJDK?

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152859 does help ?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not work for me... `-XaddExports` has been replaced by `--add-exports`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, this worked for me with AdoptJdk 11 (which is a build of OpenJdk):

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean(); 
        try { 
            Method getBytes = threadMXBean.getClass().getMethod("getThreadAllocatedBytes", long.class); 
            getBytes.setAccessible(true); 

            long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
            long bytes = (long)getBytes.invoke(threadMXBean, threadId);
            System.out.println(bytes);
        } catch (Throwable e) { 
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Invoke with

```
C:\workspaces\devtools\jdks\adoptjdk\jdk-11.0.2+9\bin\javac Test.java
C:\workspaces\devtools\jdks\adoptjdk\jdk-11.0.2+9\bin\java --add-exports jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED Test
```

Also, in that docker image it works

```
FROM jboss/base-jdk:11
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app
CMD java --add-exports jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED Test
```

And run it in docker:

```
docker build -t openjdktest .
docker run -it openjdktest
```

**EDIT**

Oh, there seems to be an even simpler alternative. Just cast your ThreadMXBean object directly to `com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean`:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = (ThreadMXBean)ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean(); 
        long bytes = threadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println(bytes);
    }
}
```

This can be run, even without the `--add-exports` JVM argument.

Comment: thanks, the solution with `--add-exports`  worked...(but the 2nd Solution did not work for me)

Comment: @CorneliaNeumüller it didn't work because the package com.sun doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

So, I just downloaded `OpenJDK 11` and extracted its sources.
Inside I found `ThreadImpl`, which implements `java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean`

[image]

And infact you can find it under

[image]

`ThreadMXBean` has indeed a `getThreadAllocatedBytes` method

```
protected long[] getThreadAllocatedBytes(long[] ids) {
    boolean verified = verifyThreadAllocatedMemory(ids);

    long[] sizes = new long[ids.length];
    java.util.Arrays.fill(sizes, -1);

    if (verified) {
        getThreadAllocatedMemory1(ids, sizes);
    }
    return sizes;
}
```

Comment: Indeed - [ThreadMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) is documented.